# Why doesn't python automatically install from requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

I've seen solutions which automatically install requirements.txt but nothing that says why Python doesn't have a feature for this.

Comment: What command you are using to install it?

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt is what you need

Comment: So what I'm asking is why can't Python see a requirements.txt file next to the script I'm running and automatically install it?

Comment: @RyanBambrough Well, you have to write code for that to install from requirements.txt, python can't install automatically do that

Comment: That is the heart of the issue that I'm curios about, why doesn't it? Is there a place to see reasoning why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the [`requirements.txt` file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) has not much to do with *Python* itself. I believe it has been created by [*pip*](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) and for pip, which is a piece of software independent from Python.

If you [search for `requirements.txt` in Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=requirements.txt) you will find only a couple of occurrences, all of them directly associated with pip. Even though [pip is somehow bundled in with distributions of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html), pip is an external project.

In short: Python doesn't know anything about `requirements.txt`, some 3rd party tools do.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

> So what I'm asking is why can't Python see a requirements.txt file next to the script I'm running and automatically install it?

This is because Python doesn't implement this feature, which makes sense because

1. Sometimes you just want to use the locally installed packages.
2. Installing new packages takes time, disk space, bandwidth, etc.
3. Different projects may have conflicting requirements.

It's not hard to implement it yourself, by the way

```
alias python="if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi; python"
```

Comment: 1. Seems like pip would take care of that for you. If locally_available: don't install

2. You're going to need to get those packages so doing it at 'run-time' doesn't seem like such a bad thing

3. This seems like the perfect application of virtualenv or something like pip install --user but more project-ified